# What is the "const gsl_vector_float" required by GSL BLAS functions?

Tags: c, gcc, blas, gsl

I am trying to use GSL to compute the dot product between two vectors.  The vectors are views of the columns of a matrix.  I call the function like `gsl_blas_dsdot( &view1.vector, &view2.vector, &val)`, but upon compilation I get warnings stating that the function expected argument types **`const gsl_vector_float *`**, and I get a nonsensical result.  Here is a code to demonstrate:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_blas.h>

void main(void){
  int i;
  double val = 111.111; // Initialize to something
  gsl_matrix *A = gsl_matrix_alloc(3,3); //Initialize mx
  gsl_matrix_set_identity(A);  // Set mx to identity
  gsl_matrix_set(A,0,1,3.14);
  gsl_vector_view a1 = gsl_matrix_column(A,0); // Vector allocations
  gsl_vector_view a2 = gsl_matrix_column(A,1);
  /* Print the vectors */
  printf("a1 = ");
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("%g ", gsl_vector_get(&a1.vector,i));}
  printf("\na2 = ");
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("%g ", gsl_vector_get(&a2.vector,i));}
  printf("\n");
  gsl_blas_dsdot(&a1.vector, &a2.vector, &val); // Dot product 
  printf("a1.a2 = %.2f\n", val);  // Print result
}
```

I compile with gcc version 5.4.0, GSL version 2.2.1, with the following:

`gcc example.c -o example -lgsl -lgslcblas`

And I get the following warnings, and though the program executes, the result is nonsensical:

```
gsl_dot.c: In function ‘main’:
gsl_dot.c:22:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gsl_blas_dsdot’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   gsl_blas_dsdot(&a1.vector, &a2.vector, &val); // Dot product 
                  ^
In file included from gsl_dot.c:4:0:
/usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_blas.h:56:5: note: expected ‘const gsl_vector_float * {aka const struct <anonymous> *}’ but argument is of type ‘gsl_vector * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
 int gsl_blas_dsdot (const gsl_vector_float * X,
     ^
gsl_dot.c:22:30: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘gsl_blas_dsdot’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   gsl_blas_dsdot(&a1.vector, &a2.vector, &val); // Dot product 
                              ^
In file included from gsl_dot.c:4:0:
/usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_blas.h:56:5: note: expected ‘const gsl_vector_float * {aka const struct <anonymous> *}’ but argument is of type ‘gsl_vector * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
 int gsl_blas_dsdot (const gsl_vector_float *
```

Note also that copying the matrix columns into `gsl_vector` types using `get_matrix_get_col()` results in the same warnings.

Can anyone please assist?  What is it about these gsl vectors and vector views that make them an incompatible type?  What are these `const gsl_vector_float` types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what a `const gsl_vector_float` is, but I did figure out that using the function `gsl_blas_ddot` instead of `gsl_blas_dsdot` compiles without warnings and executes correctly.

[According to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Level-1-GSL-BLAS-Interface.html#Level-1-GSL-BLAS-Interface), which I wish gave more detail, `gsl_blas_ddot` takes `const gsl_vector *` as argument.  This is apparently different from the `const gsl_vector_float *` in question.

Comment: A bit too late, however, you can consider gsl_vector as gsl_vector_double (since default type is double), then the difference between gsl_vector_double and gsl_vector_float becomes clear.
P.S. you can accept your own answer as correct.